# What are the special Blades Gramps mentions (and how are they unlocked)?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

After getting your first Core Crystal, Gramps mentions that with a high enough luck stat, you could spawn a special Blade. What kind of luck threshold is there and what Blades can you unlock this way?

Comment: Most probably, Gramps means 4-5 crowns Blades, which are unique, have personality, and are displayed in Blades Album. Seems to be completely random - on lvl 20 Rex, with only base Luck skill purchased, without any Luck trinkets, I've got my first unique blade from common crystal core without a single booster. It might have some percentage chance, but it's too early for community to figure it out.

Comment: Agreed. I've gotten a few since then. I got 2 out of my first 2 Rare Core Crystals, but since then I've gotten ~5 from common ones, without using boosters. I guess boosters only influence the element or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that special Blades are rare, "named" Blades that can be gotten from any core crystal. Some specific crystals give these Blades, but they can also be gotten from common and rare core crystals - rare ones have a higher base chance to give a "special" Blade.

Special Blades have their own unique intro and graphic. Some unlock specific merc missions (Azami comes to mind) where they are at the forefront.

A listing of every unique Blade (story and special) can be found [here](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/04-12-2017-xenoblade-chronicles-2-guide-tips-and-tricks/rare-blades-abilities-guide) - spoilers beware.